# Listen to transfer event on any ERC721 compliant contract (ethers.rs)

Tags: events, rust, ethers.rs

I am trying to make a program that, given a ERC721 contract address, will listen to all transfer events done on this contract until a certain point. I am not yet very familiar with how Ethereum works, but here is what I've done so far:

abi:

```
abigen!(
ERC721,
r#"[
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed tokenId)
    ]"#
);
```

Event building:

```
    let events = Contract::event_of_type::<TransferFilter>(client)
    .from_block(BlockNumber::Number(17187607.into()));
```

Stream building:

```
    let mut stream = events
    .stream_with_meta()
    .await
    .map_err(|_| "[ERROR] Invalid event stream")?
    .take(1);
```

And the the listener:

```
let event_timeout = Duration::from_secs(5);
let loop_timeout = Duration::from_secs(10);
let start = Instant::now();

while Instant::now().duration_since(start) <= loop_timeout {
    let next_event = timeout(event_timeout, stream.next());
    match next_event.await {
        Ok(Some(Ok((evt, meta)))) => {
            let from = evt.from;
            let to = evt.to;
            let zero_address = H160::from_low_u64_be(0);
            #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
            {
                println!("----------------New Event----------------");
                println!("From: {:?}", from);
                println!("To: {:?}", to);
                println!("blocknumber: {:?}", meta.block_number);
                println!("tx hash: {:?}", meta.transaction_hash);
            }
            // ... rest of the code 
        }
        Ok(Some(Err(err))) => {
            eprintln!("Error in event stream: {:?}", err);
        }
        Ok(None) | Err(_) => {
            println!("No events found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This issue is that when testing, I get to the listener, and then nothing but a timeout, it's not fetching any event.
My guess is that I didn't correctly used the abigen! macro ? I also tried to use with this JSON, but same result:
[
{
"anonymous": false,
"inputs": [
{ "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" },
{ "indexed": true, "name": "to", "type": "address" },
{ "indexed": true, "name": "tokenId", "type": "uint256" }
],
"name": "Transfer",
"type": "event"
}
]

notes:

- I'm using ehters.rs v2.0.3
- I'm kinda trying to replicate a mix between [this](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/ethers-v2.0.3/examples/subscriptions/examples/subscribe_events_by_type.rs) and [this](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/master/examples/contracts/examples/events_with_meta.rs)
- I would be really happy to get the solution, but even more to learn how it works